# I take you up and I have two friends who take you down

Tags: riddle

**Here we go, my first one. Hope you all don't find it too easy.**

Always taking people up at speed,

I do have two good friends who will take you down,

And another who takes you up too.

It is certain that I am key. Am I saying it right though.

I help people jump around docks. Oh, there must be something wrong with my tongue today.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 2):

> There are two possible answers - The PageUp key or the Up Arrow key on the keyboard.

Always taking people up at speed,

> **This refers to the fact that the PageUp or the Up Arrow take you up**

I do have two good friends who will take you down,

> **This refers to the PageDown and the Down Arrow keys on the keyboard**

And another who takes you up too.

> **Both the PageUp and the Up Arrow keys take you up. This refers to the Up Arrow key if you are using the Page Up key as the solution; It refers to the Page Up key if you are using the Up Arrow key as the solution.**

It is certain that I am key. Am I saying it right though.

> **Actually should be saying that "It is certain that I am *a* key"**. **Hence the reference to saying it right.**

I help people jump around docks. Oh, there must be something wrong with my tongue today

> **Actually should be saying that "I help people jump around *documents*". Hence the reference to something wrong with my tongue today.**

Comment: How come you answered it?

Comment: I'd still make the answer/explanations spoilers. I feel like these were too broad. There is nothing in here to make it specific enough. If the earlier clues had added up to only being the answer, then having the last two sort of screwy, misdirection clues would be fine. But because the earlier clues *weren't* specific enough, the last two might have been interpreted to support an answer that fit the earlier ones just fine.

Comment: And don't take this as an insult. This is good for your first one, but feedback can be helpful and it's food for thought, something to consider in the future.

Comment: I am not sure about what's the protocol here on the puzzling site. Just waited for a day and provided an answer; thought it would anyways go to the back of the Q and sit there otherwise. If puzzles are to be left open, I will do that from here on.

Comment: @SendersReagent, May I know why you expected the clues to be any more narrow? My very intent here was to be creative and come up with something original. Is there one "regular" riddle format that needs to be followed?

Comment: Generally, we like to give people hints before answering - a lot of people might not have even had time to see it before the solution was posted!

Comment: And as to the clues, riddles here should have one reasonable solution. The clues should all point to the solution, even if it's not in an obvious way - the solution has to stand out from all the others or it's a "guess what I'm thinking" game, not a riddle.

Comment: @Deusovi, sorry, I am a newbie to SE and this site. Will take care from my next one onwards.

Comment: No worries, everyone makes mistakes when they're new!

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea, could it be something like

> Container loading / unloading platforms

Always taking people up at speed,

I do have two good friends who will take you down,

And another who takes you up too.

> All 3 lines related to the giant "arms" taking up and down containers from cargos to warehouses and vice versa

It is certain that I am key. Am I saying it right though.

> key / quay ? But well, "I am quay" is quite non-sense...

I help people jump around docks. Oh, there must be something wrong with my tongue today.

> Containers "jumping" between docks while being moved

Comment: That's not quite okay. I will provide my comments

Answer (score 0):

**What I am ?**

> Car

Always taking people up at speed,

> Accelerator

I do have two good friends who will take you down,

> brake, clutch

And another who takes you up too.

> Gear (not sure)

It is certain that I am key. Am I saying it right though.

> Car have a key (not sure)

I help people jump around docks. Oh, there must be something wrong with my tongue today.

> Some adventures (not sure)

Comment: Sorry, but your line-answers are not matching the line-clues at all